# CSS not applying to all children

Tags: css

I have **5** elements in my page, which are exactly the same. No difference. I've written the CSS code below to animate them as they are shown

```
@keyframes statistic-item {
  0%   {transform: translateY(40px);opacity: 0;}
  30%   {transform: translateY(-20px);}
  60%   {transform: translateY(10px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0px);opacity: 1;}
}
.statistic-item {
  opacity: 0;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(0) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(1) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.1s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(2) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.2s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(3) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.3s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(4) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.4s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

The elements

```
  <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="users icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Registered Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="id badge icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Online Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="podcast icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Active Nodes</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="upload icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Total Upload</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0 Mbps</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="download icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Total Download</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0 Mbps</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But it only applies to first 3 elements. Not the last two. Why? While these elements are the same with no difference.

I'm a backend developer actually, not frontend. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the HTML code as well?

Comment: Just edited the post.

Comment: Please show the HTML - all 5 items as it's possible the problem lies there.

Comment: And note that nth-child starts at 1 so you have not done anything to animate the 5th child.

Comment: @A Haworth Thanks. Changed first index to 1. Still not applying to 5th element.

Comment: Well if you add a nth-child(5) setting to the CSS it all works.

Comment: @SoroushBgm My guess is there're some other elements before these five elements on the same level. So the first `.statistic-item` is already the 2nd or 3rd child. My suggestion is to use another type of tag for `.statistic-item`(such as `<p>` etc.) and use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) instead

Comment: @Hao Wu yeah it looks like this. I changed the indexes to 1 2 3 4 5 6. And it's working. I defined this class `statistic-item` only for these five elements. So I don't know why it looks like there is one more

Comment: `nth-child` has nothing to do with classes. The first tag with class `statistic-item` doesn't have to be the first child - it counts all the tags on the same level no matter what class you specify.

Comment: @Hao Wu Yes there is one another div on the same level. So I believe this is the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Caution: the indexing is starting at 1, not at 0.
After that small change, it works.

```css
@keyframes statistic-item {
  0%   {transform: translateY(40px);opacity: 0;}
  30%   {transform: translateY(-20px);}
  60%   {transform: translateY(10px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0px);opacity: 1;}
}
.statistic-item {
  opacity: 0;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(1) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(2) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.1s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(3) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.2s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(4) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.3s 1 normal forwards;
}
.statistic-item:nth-child(5) {
  animation: statistic-item 1s ease 0.4s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

```html
 <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="users icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Registered Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="users icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Registered Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="users icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Registered Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="users icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Registered Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="column statistic-item" style="padding: 20px;text-align: center;">
    <div class="ui segment" style="border-radius: 20px;border: 0;">
      <i style="font-size: x-large;" class="users icon red"></i>
      <p style="color: gray;">Registered Users</p>
      <p style="font-size: x-large;">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah it's working in snippet. I changed the first index to 1. Still not working for 5th element in my code! It's weird

Comment: have you added an ":nth-child(5)" selector? and you don't have a typo in the class name?

Comment: Yes I added. It was like 1 2 3 4 5. @Hao Wu mentioned the main issue in comments of the post. Which was correct.